# How to add .Image to Properties of UserControl?

Tags: vb.net, properties, user-controls

I wanted to style my Application a bit. I changed the ugly standard buttons to more beautiful ones by using labels and changing their image and some additional stuff. To gain click/mouseover feedback I started doing this(coloring the button on mousehover to grey, and change the color onClick and onMove to e.g. green[My.Settings.ColorDark]):

```
Private Sub rotate_left_MouseOver(ByVal sender As Object, _
                               ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                           Handles rotate_left.MouseMove, rotate_left.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left _
        AndAlso e.X > 0 _
        AndAlso e.X < rotate_left.Width _
        AndAlso e.Y > 0 _
        AndAlso e.Y < rotate_left.Height Then 
        rotate_left.BackColor = My.Settings.ColorDark
    Else
        If Not e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            rotate_left.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(211, 211, 211)  
        Else
            rotate_left.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(229, 229, 229) 
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rotate_left_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rotate_left.MouseLeave, FilterOn.MouseLeave
    rotate_left.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240)
End Sub
```

(I don't know anymore why I used 4 different colors - I maybe have to change that...)
This worked well, but I need to create this code every time I need a new Button (I tried to use the sender, but this wasn't working).

So I created a UserControl with the same Code. This works also works well, but I can't change the Image in the properties window (bottom right) in Visual Studio. I already added following Property, but it's not showing up :/

```
Public WriteOnly Property Image As Bitmap
    Set(ByVal value As Bitmap)
        Lbl.Image = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: remove the WriteOnly and it will show up.

Comment: @Plutonix Oh boy - that was too easy...thank you!

Comment: you should probably escape that prop name (`[Image]`) so that it doesnt get confused with the Image in `System.Drawing`

Answer (score 0):

That's a quickfix - just remove the WriteOnly Property and it will show up. You'll also need to add a `Get End Get` then...
(Don't forget to rebuild your project under Create->Rebuild Project)

```
Public Property [Image] As Bitmap
    Set(ByVal value As Bitmap)
        Lbl.Image = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return CType(Lbl.Image, Bitmap)
    End Get
End Property
```

***All props to @Plutonix***